How to make data migration with simultaneous dictionary-based transformation?
I have a source table that I want to migrate to a new system while performing a dictionary-based data transformation (its about translate the cateogry and subcategory name based on the dict table).
Ideally this could be done with a pl/sql script
The subcategory table looks like this:



Subcategory
ID_Subcategory
ID_Category




Thriller
1
1


Sci-Fi
2
1


Fantasy
3
1


Klasyka
4
1


Telefon
1
2


Komputer
2
2


Zegarek
3
2


Rock
1
3


Pop
2
3


Klasyka
3
3


Rap
4
3


Lego
1
4


Pokemon
2
4


Komedia
1
5


Dramat
2
5


Fantasy
3
5


News
1
6


Audiobook
2
6



Where category table looks like that:



Kategoria
ID_Kategoria




Książki
1


Elektronika
2


Muzyka
3


Zabawki
4


Filmy
5


Media
6



The dictionary table is as follows:



Source
Target




Książki
Books


Elektronika
Elektronics


Muzyka
Music


Zabawki
Toys


Filmy
Movies


Thriller
Thriller


Sci-Fi
Sci-Fi Fantasy


Fantasy
Sci-Fi Fantasy


Klasyka
Classic


Telefon
Phone


Komputer
Computer


Zegarek
Watch


Rock
Rock


Pop
Pop


Klasyka
Classics


Rap
Rap


Lego
Lego


Pokemon
Pokemon


Komedia
Comedy


Dramat
Drama


Fantasy
Fantasy


Media
Media


News
News


Audiobook
Audiobook



My goal is to migrate the data in such a way that for the Books category the Sci - Fi and Fanstasy subcategory is changed to Sci-Fi Fantasy (as in the dictionary).
However, for the other categories in which fantasy appears the migration should take place without changes.
The transformation with migration for the Categories table was quite easy for me because I didn't have a value there with the same key and a different value for the same key, but I can't write a properly working script to migrate the subcategories because I have two items in the dictionary where the key appears
Source = Fantasy for Target = Sci - Fi Fantasy and for the key Target = Fantasy and I don't know how to combine it to make it work
The result of subcategory table migration should look like this:



Subcategory
Subcategory_ID
Category_ID




Thriller
1001
1


Sci-Fi Fantasy
1002
1


*to be combined with Sci-Fi




Classic
1003
1


Phone
2001
2


Computer
2002
2


Watch
2003
2


Rock
3001
3


Pop
3002
3


Classics
3003
3


Rap
3004
3


Lego
4001
4


Pokemon
4002
4


Comedy
5001
5


Drama
5002
5


Fantasy
5003
5


*to be added
*to be added
*to be added


*to be added
*to be added
*to be added








UPD: What I didn't mention before thx MTO for remind me, there is another key like "Klasyka" for which there are two different values. If about the "Media" key I made a mistake in rewriting the tables, so there is only one value for that key in dict. I have edited the header in subcategory table - there was my mistake to the first column should be named Subcategory_ID. I think i should mention that there have to be some changes in Subcategory_ID in target table acording to the formula: Subcategory_ID = 1000*Category_ID + Subcategory_ID, but this is a marginal change that i won't have a problem with.

Why PL/SQL? Why not just an SQL query?

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data; a complete explanation of the logic you want to implement (including why there are two columns both named ID_Category in the first table and which table contains the Subcategory_ID values because they appear from nowhere); and your attempt at the solution.

Your dictionary has multiple rows for Fantasy, Klasyka and Media.

Assuming that your dictionary has a single mapping for each value then you can do it in a single SQL MERGE statement (without using PL/SQL):
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT t.ROWID AS rid,
         d.target,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t.id_category ORDER BY d.target) AS rnk,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY t.id_category, d.target ORDER BY t.subcategory_id
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
         INNER JOIN dictionary d
         ON (d.source = t.subcategory)
) src
ON (dst.ROWID = src.rid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET subcategory = src.target,
      subcategory_id = 1000 * id_category + rnk
  DELETE WHERE rn > 1;

Which, for the sample data (with the duplicate dictionary entries removed):
CREATE TABLE table_name (Subcategory, Subcategory_id, ID_Category) AS
SELECT CAST('Thriller' AS VARCHAR2(50)),  1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Sci-Fi',    2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fantasy',   3, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Klasyka',   4, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Telefon',   1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Komputer',  2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Zegarek',   3, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Rock',      1, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Pop',       2, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Klasyka',   3, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Rap',       4, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Lego',      1, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Pokemon',   2, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Komedia',   1, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Dramat',    2, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fantasy',   3, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'News',      1, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Audiobook', 2, 6 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE dictionary (Source, Target) AS
SELECT 'Książki', 'Books' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Elektronika', 'Elektronics' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Muzyka', 'Music' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Zabawki', 'Toys' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Filmy', 'Movies' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Thriller', 'Thriller' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Sci-Fi', 'Sci-Fi Fantasy' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fantasy', 'Sci-Fi Fantasy' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Telefon', 'Phone' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Komputer', 'Computer' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Zegarek', 'Watch' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Rock', 'Rock' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Pop', 'Pop' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Klasyka', 'Classics' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Rap', 'Rap' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Lego', 'Lego' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Pokemon', 'Pokemon' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Komedia', 'Comedy' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Dramat', 'Drama' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'News', 'News' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Audiobook', 'Audiobook' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Media', 'Media' FROM DUAL;

The, after the MERGE, the first table contains:



SUBCATEGORY
SUBCATEGORY_ID
ID_CATEGORY




Thriller
1003
1


Sci-Fi Fantasy
1002
1


Classics
1001
1


Phone
2002
2


Computer
2001
2


Watch
2003
2


Rock
3004
3


Pop
3002
3


Classics
3001
3


Rap
3003
3


Lego
4001
4


Pokemon
4002
4


Comedy
5001
5


Drama
5002
5


Sci-Fi Fantasy
5003
5


News
6002
6


Audiobook
6001
6



Note: you do not describe the logic of how to generate the Subcategory_IDs so they are just calculated from the 1000*ID_Category plus a sequential rank based on the order of the new Subcategory within each ID_Category partition.
fiddle
